# Rate of change with $a(t)=\frac{1}{t+4}$ on $[9,9+h]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working on an exercise to find the rate of change between points $[9, 9+h]$ with the function $a(t)=\frac{1}{t+4}$.

The solution provided is $\frac{-1}{13(13+h)}$ whereas I arrive at $\frac{\frac{1}{h}}{h}$.

My working:

$a(t_1)$ = $\frac{1}{9+4}$ = $\frac{1}{13}.$

$x(t_2)$ = $\frac{1}{9+h+4}$ = $\frac{1}{13+h}.$

The rate of change is: $\frac{a(t_2)-a(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}.$

So: $\dfrac{\frac{1}{13+h}-\frac{1}{13}}{9+h-9}$ = $\dfrac{\frac{1}{13}+\frac{1}{h}-\frac{1}{13}}{h}$ = $\dfrac{\frac{1}{h}}{h}.$

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at $\frac{-1}{13(13+h)}$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{13+h}-\frac{1}{13} \not = \frac{1}{13}+\frac{1}{h}-\frac{1}{13}$ but $\frac{1}{13+h}-\frac{1}{13} = \frac{h}{13(13+h)}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because$$\frac1{13+h}\neq\frac1{13}+\frac1h.$$In fact\begin{align}\frac1{13+h}-\frac1{13}&=\frac{13}{(13+h)13}-\frac{13+h}{(13+h)13}\\&=\frac{13-13-h}{(13+h)13}\\&=-\frac h{(13+h)13}.\end{align}

Comment: Hi thank you. May I ask, how can one arrive at `$\frac{h}{(13+h)13}$`?

Comment: Guess Math type does not work in comments.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{a\pm b} \ne\frac{1}{a}\pm\frac{1}b$$

So, $$\frac{1}{13+h}-\frac{1}{13} = \frac{13-13-h}{(13+h)13}=-\frac{h}{13(13+h)}$$

Answer (score 1):

You made the critical mistake of writing
$$\frac1{13+h}=\frac1{13}+\frac1h$$
when this is in fact completely wrong. Starting from the last correct step:
$$\frac{\frac1{13+h}-\frac1{13}}{9+h-9}=\frac{\frac{13-(13+h)}{13(13+h)}}h$$
$$=\frac{-h}{13h(13+h)}=\frac{-1}{13(13+h)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{13+h}\neq\frac{1}{13}+\frac{1}{h}$$